# Runntime error 2115

Tags: ms-access

Getting Runtime error 2115 while doing data validation in the BeforeUpdate procedure in MS Access.
here:

```
Private Sub Option_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
  If Option = A Then
    Answer=MsgBox("You mean B?",vbYesNo)
    If Answer = vbYes Then
      Cancel = True
      Option = B
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option = B
```

You can't update a control while updating it ...

But you can do it after:

```
Private Sub Option_AfterUpdate()

  If Option = A Then
    Answer = MsgBox("You mean B?", vbYesNo)
    If Answer = vbYes Then
      Option = B
    End If
  End If

End Sub
```